# Python write to csv in rows

Tags: python, list, csv

Probably basic Python, but I can't get my head around it.

I have some results from a function which print as `[{1,2,3},{4,5,6),{7,8,9}]`. I want to write this to a csv like this:

```
A      B     C
1      2     3
4      5     6
7      8     9
```

With this code (note the `writerow.`):

```
filename = 'test.csv'

sr = []
for row in result:
    sr.append(row)

with open(filename, "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=';')
    writer.writerow(sr)
```

I get:

```
A        B        C
{1,2,3}  {4,5,6}  {7,8,9}
```

When I use `writer.writerows(sr)` I get `_csv.Error: sequence expected`. Which makes perfect sense because my initial result is just one row.

How to transform the data in such a way that I can get it to a csv like I want?

Comment: Each item in your result, is a `set`, not a sequence, which is what `writerow()` wants. `writerow(list(sr))` should work.

Comment: It does work. However, it puts every set in a single cell. It should split each set in single values and continue on a new line for every set.

Answer (score 1):

If your result looks like this:

```py
result = [{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {8, 9, 7}]
```

You could write it directly using `writerows`:

```py
import csv

with open('test.csv', 'w') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f, delimiter=';')
    w.writerows(result)
```

`writerows` takes an `iterable` of `iterable` which is a `set` in your case but if you use `writerow` instead it'll write your `result` in a single line which give a `set` per column

Comment: `Print(result)` does give me the structure you posted. But I keep getting the `_csv.Error: sequence expected` when I use you code. Tried some other options, which write the result but as {1, 2, 3} in the first cell and then {4, 5, 6} in the cell next to it.

Comment: could you add a sample of your `sr` variable

Answer (score 0):

To get the format the way you want would require something along these lines:

```
import csv

result = [{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {8, 9, 7}]
filename = 'testabc.csv'
header = 'A', 'B', 'C'

with open(filename, "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=';')
    writer.writerows(header)
    for row in result:
        writer.writerow(list(row))
```

A potential problem is that `set`s don't preserve order, so the items may end up in random order with each row (unless you manually sorted them).